# customtkinter: How to dynamically resize Frame with window using place()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

So I use `place()` instead of `grid()` or `pack()` because afaik, they all serve the same purpose if you know how to use one of them correctly.
I have a 800x600 window with a 800x600 frame within it, when I resize the window the frame remains 800x600. What I want is the frame resizing itself (along with it's content) to the new window size but I don't how so thank you in advance!

Here is how I create and place my frame in the window:

```
bgFrame = customtk.CTkFrame(app, fg_color="white", width=800, height=600)
bgFrame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
```

Comment: Set `relwidth=1` and `relheight=1` in `bgFrame.place(...)`.

Comment: They serve the same purpose, but `pack` and `grid` do a lot more for you. Using `place` requires that you do more work to make the UI responsive.

Comment: Thank you both. acw1668, can you post your comment as an answer so I can flag it as the right answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a widget (using `.place()` as the layout manager) to be resized when its parent is resized, then you need to set both `relwidth` and `relheight` options of `.place(...)` to 1:

```py
bgFrame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relwidth=1, relheight=1, anchor="center")
```